# How to investigate a server crash being caused by hardware or software?

Tags: ubuntu, crash, hp-proliant

I've been running a home server for years, but recently it started failing. what happens is that the server keeps running, I hear the fan spins, lights stay on and the screen "stays on". But the SSH connection becomes unavailable, the server is not on the network anymore and the connected screen with console still outputs the console, but shows blue dots randomly on the screen.

I've tried several things now but totally stuck on what I can try next.
I've tried:

- Looking trough all logs in /var/log
- Reinstalled from ubuntu 14.06 to 20.06
- Cleaned the whole server from dust and renewed the cooling paste on the CPU + have monitored with `sensors` command to ensure it's not an overheating issue.

Also some other potential useful information:

- Server: HP Proliant Microserver (HPE Proliant N36L)
- Orignally was installed with windows server
- I'm using on both installations the ldmtool to mount the 2x 2TB disks in raid mode on the server.

Happy to provide any more information that might be useful! And looking forward to any suggestions, that will help debug, to find the issue!

Comment: Check IML via iLO , also what interface is your ssh on ?
Have you check the psu output via atx connector?

Comment: I need to figure out how to access the IML via iLO, is that something I can reach on startup or trough the bios window?

On the power supply unit, all power values reported by sensors are correct. other than that I don't think have the right tools to check the power output. (or know the right way)

Comment: Potentially valuable to add, I have been monitoring the outages scheme. and there is no pattern at all. some times it lasts 1,5 hour, 2,5h or more then a day before the issue occurs.

Comment: I would do a memory test -> memtest86 or passmark or even windows memory diagnostic first , then afterwards check the voltage of the ATX connector on the psu , with the powerok and ground pins shorted and measure the voltage using a multimeter , it seems your server does not have an iLO interface so we cannot check internal logs

Comment: How old is your server?

Comment: I think it's about 10 years old by now. Tonight I'll dive into a memtest and any other suggestions made. sadly windows memory diagnostic won't be available as it's reinstalled as ubuntu server.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/118993/discussion-between-binaryops20-and-spons).